# How to show all tables/views in ER diagram with DbVisualizer

Tags: dbvisualizer

Is there a setting in DbVisualizer to display all tables in the "References" tab? I am using the free version (10.0) and when I click on a table with the References tab open I only see the direct relationships from this table. I'd like to see all tables in the schema.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the left-hand pane, double-click on the database name while having the References tab open to have all tables displayed.

Answer (score 9):

In the **Databases** tab, double-click on the **TABLE** entry (that has all the tables under it), then select the **References** tab.

Answer (score 8):

> Easy to direct in visuals

1. Right-click on schema (ex- scott) > Open in Tab
   [image]
2. Click on **References** Tab
   [image]